# Gradle build failing due to dependency issues

Tags: gradle

We have declared `ojb:db-ojb:1.0.4` which is required for compiling our project , but we are getting the below issue , it is searching for dependency commons-`transaction:commons-transaction:1.1` , but we have `org.apache.commons.transaction:commons-transaction:1.1` in archiva. Could you check and let us know how we can avoid checking for dependency for commons-transaction or any other solutions to handle this in gradle:

```
[04:14:17][Gradle failure report] > Could not resolve commons-transaction:commons-transaction:1.1.
[04:14:17][Gradle failure report] Required by:
[04:14:17][Gradle failure report] com.e2open.e2mc:IOMe:8.2 > ojb:db-ojb:1.0.4
[04:14:17][Gradle failure report] > Could not resolve commons-transaction:commons-transaction:1.1.
[04:14:17][Gradle failure report] > inconsistent module metadata found.     Descriptor: org.apache.commons.transaction:commons-transaction:1.1 Errors: bad group: expected='commons-transaction' found='org.apache.commons.transaction'
```

Comment: You need to include your Gradle config file as well.

Comment: The very last line of the error message gives you a good hint:

> [04:14:17][Gradle failure report] > inconsistent module metadata found.     Descriptor: org.apache.commons.transaction:commons-transaction:1.1 Errors: bad group: expected='commons-transaction' found='org.apache.commons.transaction'

So it looks like the metadata (pom.xml) and the structure of your repo are incosistent. The group of booth should be _org.apache.commons.transaction_. Which repo are you using (maven central or something within your infrastructure)? Could you please provide us the pom.xml of commons-transaction?